# Using WPF and Prism, how to resolve a dependency not using constructor injection

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

In a ViewModel, is there a way to resolve a dependency using PRISM that is not by contructor injection?  In Caliburn Micro you can do something like

```
_myService = IoC.Get<IMyService>();
```

but is there a way to do the same thing in PRISM? Example?

Comment: why would you want to do that? there's a 99% chance there's better way to achieve what you're trying to do without injecting the container... (but of course, you can inject `IUnityContainer`)

Answer (score 1):

PRISM is bundled with Unity and MEF for dependency injection - and both support property injection as well as constructor injection. If you don't want to use constructor injection, you can use the relevant attribute and tag injectable properties.

https://prismlibrary.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WPF/03-Managing-Dependencies/#using-dependency-injection-containers-and-services-in-prism